# Update value in table from Dialog Angular MAterial

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have Material Dialog, where I need to update the entry in a table by clicking Change Status button.

Here working snippet

> https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-alu8pa

Now I've been able to get data from dialog. You can see it console from snippet. But I need to update entry from table with this data.

Reason and StatusDescription fields.

Here is my Dialog component code

```
  import {Component, Inject, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation} from '@angular/core';
import {MAT_DIALOG_DATA, MatDialogRef, MatDialog} from "@angular/material";
import {FormBuilder, Validators, FormGroup} from "@angular/forms";
import { Payment } from '../payments/payment';


@Component({
    selector: 'editing-dialog',
    templateUrl: './editing-dialog.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./editing-dialog.component.scss']
})
export class EditingDialogComponent implements OnInit {
    form: FormGroup;
    reason:String;
    id: Number;
    statusdescription: String;

    constructor(
        private fb: FormBuilder,
        private dialogRef: MatDialogRef<EditingDialogComponent>,
        @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) data:Payment) {
            this.reason = data.Reason;
            this.id  = data.Id;
            this.statusdescription = data.StatusDescription;
            this.form = fb.group({
                reason: [this.reason, Validators.required],
                id: this.id,
                status: status
            });
    }

    ngOnInit() {

    }
    save() {
        this.dialogRef.close(this.form.value);
    }

    close() {
        this.dialogRef.close();
    }
}
```

By save() method I get data from dialog.

And I'm subscribing in payments component

Here is code of it.

```
  import { Component, AfterViewInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import {MatTableDataSource, MatPaginator, MatDialog, MatDialogConfig, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material';
import { PAYMENTS } from "./payments-mock";
import { EditingDialogComponent } from '../editingdialog/editing-dialog.component';
import { Payment } from './payment';



@Component({
  selector: 'app-payments',
  templateUrl: './payments.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./payments.component.scss']
})
export class PaymentsComponent implements AfterViewInit {

  constructor(private dialog: MatDialog) {}

    openDialog(Id, Currency, Amount,Reason,StatusDescription) {
      const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();

      dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
      dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;

      dialogConfig.data = {
          Id: Id,
          Reason: Reason,
          StatusDescription: StatusDescription
      };

      if
      (Currency.trim() === "UAH"){
        alert("You can’t approve such payment today. It is not a bank day for this currency.");

      }
      if(Currency.trim() == "EUR" && Amount > 4000)
      {
        alert("You have no authority to approve such payment. Please, ask your manager to do it");
      }


      const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(EditingDialogComponent, dialogConfig);
      dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
        data => console.log("Dialog output:", data)
    );    
    }


  //Default values to checkboxes
  pending = false;
  approved = false;
  rejected = false;

  //List of displaying columns
  displayedColumns = ['PaymentDate','Amount','StatusDescription','Reason','Action'];
  dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(PAYMENTS);


  @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
    this.dataSource.filterPredicate =
     (data, filter: string) => !filter || data.StatusDescription === filter;
  }

  //Methods for checkboxes
  pendingModelChecked(value: any) {
    const filter = value ? 'Pending' : null
    this.dataSource.filter = filter;
  }

  approvedModelChecked(value: any) {
    const filter = value ? 'Approved' : null
    this.dataSource.filter = filter;
  }

  rejectedModelChecked(value: any) {
    const filter = value ? 'Rejected' : null
    this.dataSource.filter = filter;
  }
}
```

How I can update row from table with new data correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the following to accomplish this.

Pass the root element `payment` as an argument to `openDialog()`, you could also reduce your `openDialog()` to only needing this one argument if you wanted to.

```
<button mat-button (click)="openDialog(payment.Id, payment.Currency, payment.Amount, payment.Reason,payment.StatusDescription, payment)">Change Status</button>
```

add `payment` as additional argument

```
openDialog(Id, Currency, Amount, Reason, StatusDescription, payment) {
```

then set the values in your `afterClose()` subscription

```
 dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(
      data => {
        console.log("Dialog output:", data)
        payment.Reason = data.reason;
        payment.StatusDescription = data.status
      }
    );
```

**Stackblitz**

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wfvqbj?embed=1&file=src/app/payments/payments.component.html

---

Passing the specific arguments `payment.Id` for example make them local to the function and decouple them from the original root record, re-assigning the values do not effect the caller... passing the entire root element is a way around this and will allow changes made to bubble up to the view as the root element is now in scope of the function.

Comment: see revision to answer with additional information on why this works.